# Django staticfiles and CSS and javaScript

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-staticfiles, django-1.3

I'm using django 1.3 for production and want to use static file's in my CSS and javaScript but it doesn't work , I don't have any problem in my HTML ! how must solve this problem ? I didn't find any solution in django doc .

I use this code for adding static files to my CSS :

```
{% load static %}
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %}
#main {
     background-image: url("{{ STATIC_PREFIX }}img.png");
}
```

I'm using this template tag `{% load static %} {% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %}` in my html and it works fine but I dunno why it doesn't work in CSS !!!

Comment: You gotta run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS files aren't rendered by the Django templating engine, they are just served by your web server, so you can't use the Django template language.

If you really wanted to (and this is an exceptionally bad idea) you could serve you CSS files through Django by creating URLs and views that render the CSS files, allowing you to make use of the template language.

Comment: ty , is there any tutorial and what is the best way for doing this ?

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for static CSS and image files is here: [Current Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) and [Django Documentation 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/).

In your settings.py you'll want to set

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/full/page/to/static/',
)
```

Then you can store your images and css files under that '/full/page/to/static/' directory. 
In your template you would use your css and images like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.css">
<img src="/static/header.png" alt="Company Header" />
```

In addition to that you can add a directory structure under the "/static/" directory and it will reflect in URL.

For example

```
/full/path/to/static/img
/full/path/to/static/css
```

Would resolve to:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/styles.css">
    <img src="/static/img/header.png" alt="Company Header" />
```

Comment: ty bro but I asked for something else